# High Disk Write failure in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

**Couchbase: 6.5**

**Cluster Size:**

`Node A`: 16 GB, 4 Core

`Node B`: 16 GB, 4 Core

**Total Buckets:** 20

**Bucket Type:** Couchabse

For some buckets seeing thousands of Disk Write Failure [ep_data_write_failed] on `Node B`.

Issue Started when `Node B` utilised 100% of the disk space. We increased the disk space to resolve the issue, but the `ep_data_write_failed` is still more than 80K.

On `Node B` 1 min Load average is around 9

`memcached.log`  is showing the following errors:

```
2022-12-28T08:37:33.480485+00:00 WARNING (bucket_name) Slow runtime for 'Updating stat snapshot on disk' on thread writer_worker_2: 369 ms
2022-12-28T08:37:33.544540+00:00 WARNING (bucket_name) Slow runtime for 'Updating stat snapshot on disk' on thread writer_worker_3: 350 ms
2022-12-28T08:37:33.560675+00:00 WARNING (bucket_name) Slow runtime for 'Item pager on vb:1024' on thread nonIO_worker_0: 418 ms
2022-12-28T08:37:33.816981+00:00 WARNING (bucket_name) Slow runtime for 'Item pager on vb:1024' on thread nonIO_worker_1: 976 ms
2022-12-28T08:37:34.593583+00:00 WARNING (bucket_name) Slow runtime for 'Item pager on vb:1024' on thread nonIO_worker_1: 776 ms
2022-12-28T08:37:35.586048+00:00 WARNING (bucket_name) Slow runtime for 'Item pager on vb:1024' on thread nonIO_worker_1: 990 ms
2022-12-28T08:37:36.266331+00:00 WARNING (bucket_name) Slow runtime for 'Item pager on vb:1024' on thread nonIO_worker_0: 679 ms
2022-12-28T08:37:37.000314+00:00 WARNING (bucket_name) Slow runtime for 'Item pager on vb:1024' on thread nonIO_worker_0: 733 ms
2022-12-28T08:37:37.707179+00:00 WARNING (bucket_name) Slow runtime for 'Item pager on vb:1024' on thread nonIO_worker_0: 706 ms
2022-12-28T08:37:38.552471+00:00 WARNING (bucket_name) Slow runtime for 'Item pager on vb:1024' on thread nonIO_worker_0: 844 ms
2022-12-28T08:37:39.408739+00:00 WARNING (bucket_name) Slow runtime for 'Item pager on vb:1024' on thread nonIO_worker_0: 852 ms
2022-12-28T08:37:40.257125+00:00 WARNING (bucket_name) Slow runtime for 'Item pager on vb:1024' on thread nonIO_worker_0: 846 ms
2022-12-28T08:37:41.067766+00:00 WARNING (bucket_name) Slow runtime for 'Item pager on vb:1024' on thread nonIO_worker_0: 810 ms
```

Did anyone faced the same issue? Need help in understanding the log messages.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in answering.  One thing to keep in mind is that the 'ep_data_write_failed' is an incrementing counter, and so will always remain high until reset.  The important thing is that it isn't continuing to increase.